# Centering entire page

Tags: css

My website is left-justified with a lot of absolute positioning:

```
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: 200px;
```

I'd like to center it, like NYtimes.com does.

Is there CSS I can use to do this?

Comment: We'll need to see the HTML so we can tell you which element to add `margin: 0 auto;` to ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you didn't searched on google/stackoverflow for a solution :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link below solved my problem:

http://www.zachgraeve.com/2006/10/01/center-abosulte-position-div/

Since I have absolute positioning, I have to use the trick in the link above.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="centerwrap">  

HTML code for entire webpage

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#centerwrap { 
     position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px; 
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can center it by wrapping the whole content of the website in a wrapper div like:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
page content
</div> <!-- end #wrapper -->
</body>
```

Then, give the wrapper div a width and center it with margins, e.g.

```
#wrapper { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Will this work if items inside the div tag have absolute positioning?

Comment: Why not test it and see what happens instead of asking simple questions? AP works from top left of your browser, you can still AP an element outside of the wrapper div, so depending on what you have right now, you might need to change the AP of soem elements. But you should'nt be using AP so much to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basics on how to center your site, basically wrap everything on a DIV and center that.

http://jsfiddle.net/9tbuB/